CORS error despite setting CORS headers on the server in a WebSocket connection
I am trying to establish a websocket connection between my angular(17) frontend and python backend for a chatbot.
For the client side, I am using the ngx-socket-io for websocket. Here is the relevant code for that.
This is the app.config.ts file. Herein, I am configuring the SocketIoModule as per the instructions given in ngx-socekt-io github page here - https://github.com/rodgc/ngx-socket-io/blob/master/README.md
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

const config: SocketIoConfig = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8765',
  options: {}
};

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule), 
    importProvidersFrom(SocketIoModule.forRoot(config))
  ]
};

Here is the service that I created - following instruction from same github page.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {
  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

  sendMessage(msg: string){
    console.log("Sending the message through a socket");
    this.socket.emit('message', msg);
  }
  getMessage(){
    return this.socket.fromEvent('message').pipe(map((data:any) => data.msg));
  }
}


For the backend, I am using python websockets library.
Here is the simple server code.
import asyncio
import websockets
from chat import process_chat, agentExectuor

agentExectuor = agentExectuor()

async def hello(websocket, path):

    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    }

    await websocket.prepare(websocket)
    await websocket.send_headers(headers)

    async for user_input in websocket:
        print(str(user_input))
        response = process_chat(agentExectuor, str(user_input))
        await websocket.send(response)


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Disclaimer - websockets documentation doesn't even mention the word CORS. In fact, when I had checked connection by writing client side code in vanilla javascript, it was not giving any CORS errors. Therefore, I have asked ChatGPT for a way to add CORS headers for the response and this is what GPT suggested me - prepare and send_headers lines.
When I run the frontend with ng serve, I can see a websocket type packet which has response status code 101 meaning that protocol change has occurred and it seems as if the connection is established. Here is the snapshot of that. I am very sorry if I am misconstruing this.
A snapshot of this is attached here -
websocket packet image
Why does this have url as ws://localhost:4200? At 4200, my angular frontend is running. Shouldn't this be ws://localhost:8765?
After that, console gives a CORS error -
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8765/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P0gBFXz' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

After CORS error, There is a get request to this URL - http://localhost:8765/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P0gBFXz - whose response packet is like this.
This one has 426(upgrade required). A snapshot of this is attached here -
get request response packet image
I have tried changing URL in my config file to ws instead of http. It didn't help.
I have also tried setting particular CORS origin to be localhost:4200 but that did not work either.
